# creating two variables based on selective elimination and pair combinations

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, tidyr

I have a data of the following form. The data has information about three projects- 1, 2,3 and I would like to calculate the trips of colleagues and purchases till prior year but I want to eliminate all the projects in which he is taking part till that point(and only consider projects in which he is not part of). For example, see below:

```
 id<- c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3)
 person<- c('John','Kevin', 'John', 'Matt', 'Alvin', 'Kevin', 'Alvin')
 trips<- c(4,2,5,2,3,4,5)
 purchase<- c(6,4,3,4,5,5,6)
 join_year<- c(2009,2008,2008,2007,2007, 2008,2008)
 df<- data.frame(id, person, trips, purchase, year)
```

I would like to create two variables called pr_trips_colleagues (referring to prior year) and pr_purchases_colleagues(referring to prior year). I would like to have a final output as follows:

```
     person      year          pr_trips_colleagues  pr_purchase_colleagues 
     John        2009                  5             6
     John        2008                  0             0
     John        2007                  0             0
     Kevin       2009                  8             8
     Kevin       2008                  0             0
     Kevin       2007                  0             0
     Matt        2009                  5             6
     Matt        2008                  0             0
     Matt        2007                  0             0
     Alvin       2009                  2             4
     Alvin       2008                  0             0
     Alvin       2007                  0             0
```

Please provide suggestions on how to obtain this? Thanks so much.

Comment: I changed that to join year to indicate that he joined in that year

Comment: You are right it should be same across..

Comment: I've read this 3 times and I have no idea how you are getting that result from that input. Can you give any more detail on how the values in the final output are calculated?

Comment: For example, let’s take John, he has participated in two projects 1 and 2 though he joined 1 in 2009 and 2 in 2008, so for calculating the 2007, he will 0 and 0 as he did not have colleagues till 2006, then for 2008, we need to look his activities till 2007, so the values won’t change as he did not join any project, but for 2009, we need to look at his projects till 2008, he took part in project 2, so Matt and Alvin became colleagues, and Alvin took part in project 3 in which John was not part of, hence the values become  5 and 6 respectively, Kevin became colleague to John in 2009 so not incl

Comment: Replace the word till with in in the comment above

Comment: Essentially they are lagged values of his colleagues, thanks so much, let me know if makes sense

Comment: That makes more sense.

Comment: Also the values are not running totals, just lagged, so for 2008 we will consider the 2007 effects only, thanks again, cheers!